# SQLite Exception near %, syntax error while compiling ... Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am implementing search in an app which I am making, I am writing this line in my dbhelper class search method and the app crashes when I press enter or backspace in the editText which I have hooked to onkeylistener...

```
   Cursor c = sqldb.query(courseTable, columnNames, course + " LIKE %?%", selectionVals, null, null, null);
```

I am getting this error/exception in logcat

```
H/AndroidRuntime(21777): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT course_name, assessment_type, obtained_marks, total_marks FROM Course WHERE course_name LIKE %?%
```

I am stuck here. How to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: how about this `Cursor c = sqldb.query(courseTable, columnNames, course + " LIKE '%?%'", selectionVals, null, null, null);` ... quoted with `'`

Comment: You must delimit strings with apostrophes - `LIKE '%?%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this issue if you add wildcards to the selectionVal instead of adding it to the filter like this.

```
selectionVals[0] = "%" + selectionVals[0] + "%";

Cursor c = sqldb.query(courseTable, columnNames, 
     course + " LIKE ?", selectionVals, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need single quotes around your wildcards.

So

```
sqldb.query(courseTable, columnNames, course + " LIKE %?%", selectionVals, null, null, null);
```

becomes

```
sqldb.query(courseTable, columnNames, course + " LIKE '%?%'", selectionVals, null, null, null);
```

I'm not sure about escaping them, you may need to do that if the java compiler complains about it.

Hope that helps!